# Why processing keeps saying "SyntaxError : Expected ; but found size" but it run just ok in p5.js online editor?

Tags: processing, p5.js

The processing console keeps saying Syntax Error: Expected ; but found size. I have copy pasted my code to p5.js online editor and it ran just fine.

```
var ur;
var x;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400,400);
  x=width;
  ur = getURL();
}

function draw() {
  background(100);
  fill(0);
  noStroke();
  let size = 9;
  textSize(size);
  text(ur,x,height/2);
  x--;
  if(x<-1*(ur.length)*size) x = width;
}
```

Comment: Processing uses Java and p5.js uses JavaScript

Comment: What editor are you using? This is JavaScript. It won't work in the Processing editor's Java mode. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Oh, does the processing editor have a p5.js mode? Or is it for processing.js? @KevinWorkman

Comment: @LukeGarrigan I think he means the [p5.js Web Editor](https://editor.p5js.org/) for online editor and p5.js mode in the Processing IDE regarding the Console Error

Comment: So i just realized size was reserved variable in processing IDE. when i change the size name to something else it works

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with let, but with the use of 'size' as a variable name, which is (or was, see [this ticket](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/3297) for more info) a reserved word in p5.js. If you change 'size' to 'theSize', for example, things should work fine.

Comment: right, size was variable name in processing editor. that was my naming mistake